# How would you explain this theory of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

> The number of edges is the sum of the degrees of all vertices divided by 2.

Would I use the Sum of Degrees of Vertices Theorem to explain this?
Not sure how to explain this in one easy sentence and would like some help.

Comment: What is the "Sum of Degrees of Vertices Theorem"? Is it the theorem which says that the sum of the degrees is equal to twice the number of edges? If so, then I think you're right, that is the theorem to use here.

Comment: This is the exact written description of the Sum of Degrees of Vertices theorem: "the sum of the degrees of the vertices equals twice the number of edges."

Comment: But, as stated by @ParclyTaxel the Hand-Shaking Lemma states: "the sum of the vertex degrees is equal to twice the number of edges."

Comment: What! They're the same!

Comment: That's the descriptions that I have. I guess they both work (Vice Versa)?

Comment: They both work. More importantly, their content is exactly the same.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel So your answer would apply for both of the stated theorem/lemma?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the hand-shaking lemma. It can be easily seen from the fact that each edge has two endpoints, thus contributing two to the sum of the vertex degrees. Therefore the number of edges is half that sum of vertex degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: each edge connects to, and thus contributes to the degrees of, exactly two vertices.